# Are questions enabled while being edited?

Tags: support

If I'm editing one question I've made, is this question available for other users to answer and comment it during this process, or it gets blocked for a while?

Comment: Why would it be blocked from answering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user < 2K reputation submit an `suggested edit` the post goes in to suggested edit review queue.

In that case editing link gets block for the users < 2K reputation. But the users > 2K can see it as `edit(1)` link and can review it.

But sometimes it is possible that while you have click on edit link and doing editing work, the other user > 2K reputation can edit that post without any lock and while you are doing editing, it shows a notification on top of the browser that this post has been already edited and your editing will go into review queue.

Answer (score 4):

If I edit question made by you, this question is *still available* for other users to give *answer* and *comment* during *entire process*, or it not get *blocked*.

After edited you and other viewer saws **edited 10 seconds ago** or same as different time period *bottom of the post*.

Answer (score 2):

It is still available while editing.

If you have 2k+ (or it's your own post) then it will be edited immediately when you click "Submit," and people viewing the post will see a banner that says "This post had been edited, click to load new edit."

Otherwise, your edit must be reviewed. People can still see the post while it is being reviewed though.

The post will **never** be blocked.